# PHP Subtract 1 from database conditional

Tags: php, mysql

The below 2 lines updates the database after a comment is deleted by subtracting -1 from `comment_total`. I'm getting an error if `comment_total` happens to be 0 since we can't subtract -1 from 0. How can i modify this so it subtracts -1 only if `comment_total` is larger then 0, otherwise set it to 0.

```
$query = $this->EE->db->query("SELECT comment_total FROM exp_channel_titles WHERE entry_id = '$entry_id'");
$this->EE->db->query("UPDATE exp_channel_titles set comment_total = '".($query->row('comment_total') - 1)."' WHERE entry_id = '$entry_id'");
```

Comment: you can add second where clause like this at the end `AND comment_total > 0` ?

Comment: btw you can subtract -1 from 0, perhaps your thinking of dividing by 0 ?

Comment: @ben, that's what i thought. But i get the error when -1 is subtracted from 0. `Fatal error: Unsupported operand types`.

Comment: @Pinkie, strange. Does it work if you + 1 or any other number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this entirely on the database side using a single query

```
UPDATE exp_channel_titles SET comment_total = GREATEST(comment_total - 1, 0)
WHERE entry_id = ?
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. I added the `max` function:

```
$query = $this->EE->db->query("SELECT comment_total FROM exp_channel_titles WHERE entry_id = '$entry_id'");
$this->EE->db->query("UPDATE exp_channel_titles set comment_total = '".max(0,$query->row('comment_total') - 1)."' WHERE entry_id = '$entry_id'");
```

Documentation for `max` can be found here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php

Comment: I'm still getting same error. `Fatal error: Unsupported operand types`. if i manually replace `$query->row('comment_total') - 1` with 0 then it works.

Comment: ah, that error isn't about your query, but your php code. What does `$query->row('comment_total')` return?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the ticks (quotes) that were around the value to which comment_total was being set.

```
if ($query->row('comment_total') > 0) {
    $this->EE->db->query("UPDATE exp_channel_titles set comment_total = ".($query->row('comment_total') - 1)." WHERE entry_id = '$entry_id'");
}
```

Comment: Oh ok bummer. I gave it the ol' college try!